# Setting Current User using Parse and Facebook

Tags: facebook, parse-platform

I just started using Parse and am very excited to get my app up and running, but am having an issue getting the current user in my server code.

I am using Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn to register and log in users for my Parse application.

After a user logs in, calling Parse.User.current() produces the correct result on the client side, but returns null on the server side.

Do I need to explicitly set the current user in my cloud code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Calls to Cloud Code have the current user in `request.user`, you don't user `Parse.User.current()` server-side since they aren't logged in server-side.

```
var currentUser = request.user;
```

That's the code you use in the cloud.